# How to start a thread in telethon correctly?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, telethon

I am writing a bot and I need to implement the following functionality: the bot once every 10 minutes(for example) parse a certain URL and if there were changes from the previous call, writes to the chat.
Since the bot is also engaged in other things, I decided to loop the parsing in the function with sleep at the end. If there are changes, I try to send a message to the chat, but then a problem happens.
Since a successful combination of circumstances does not arise from an event in the chat, I can't pull the "entity" from the "event" for the "send_message" function. therefore, we have to get through the "get_entity" function and links to the chat as a parameter, but for some reason this does not work from another stream. below is a simplified code:

```
import threading, queue
from time import sleep
import asyncio
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import config as cfg

bot = TelegramClient('Bot', cfg.api_id, cfg.api_hash)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'^(?i)(idchat){1}$'))
async def echoidchat(event):
    channelaa = await bot.get_entity('https://t.me/elvistest')
    await bot.send_message(channelaa, 'ответ')


def parseurls():
    for x in range(10):
        q.put(x)
    pass
    

async def pre_sendmsg():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = q.get_nowait()
        except Exception as e:
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        else:
            await sendmsg(msg)
            q.task_done()

async def sendmsg(msg):
    channel = await bot.get_entity('https://t.me/elvistest')
    await bot.send_message(channel, f'ответ из другого потока {msg}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = queue.Queue()
    parseurls()
    bot.start(bot_token=cfg.bot_token)
    threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, daemon=True, args=(pre_sendmsg(),)).start()
    bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

The thing is that on the line " boot.get_entity" nothing happens. The script execution is lost somewhere and does not go further, that is, the next line with "bot. send_message" is simply not executed. however, "def echoidchat" is working at this time.

Comment: You are using `async` so you there is no need to run your async function (pre_sendmsg) in another thread. Simply doing `asycio.create_task(pre_sendmsg())` is fine. Also, `q` is most likely not defined in pre_sendmsg

Comment: You should use `asyncio.Queue` which supports fetching items asynchronously.

Comment: You are using telethon.sync which won't play nicely with whatever you're doing. Stop using the .sync package.

Comment: I tried all your suggested options, but still my code also stops at " boot.get_entity"

Answer (score 0):

Well done!
This is work like I want.

```
import random
import threading, queue
from time import sleep
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import config as cfg

bot = TelegramClient('Bot', cfg.api_id, cfg.api_hash)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'^(?i)(idchat){1}$'))
async def echoidchat(event):
    await bot.send_message(event.chat, 'ответ')


async def parseurls():
    while True:
        ts = abs(int(random.random()*10))
        print(f'parseurls({ts})')
        await sendmsg(ts)
        await asyncio.sleep(ts)


async def sendmsg(msg):
    print(f'sendmsg({msg}) - start')
    channel = await bot.get_entity('https://t.me/elvistest')
    await bot.send_message(channel, f'ответ из другого потока {msg}')
    print(f'sendmsg({msg}) - done')


def main():
    bot.start(bot_token=cfg.bot_token)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [
        loop.create_task(parseurls()),
        loop.create_task(bot.run_until_disconnected()),
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```